# Допустимо ли большое количество асинхронных компонентов?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

очень понравились мне асинхронные компоненты, делаю админку для сайта на laravel и так же использую vue-route в админке. Подскажите пожалуйста если у меня на одной странице подгружается сразу 6 компонентов асинхронно, хорошо ли это или плохо ? Может быть стоит делать как то более компактно, что бы не было много запросов к серверу, я ещё использую же vue-route, все эти компоненты копятся в теге head, это на одной странице 6 компонентов а когда перейду на другую будет к примеру ещё +3 или +4 компонентов.

Comment: Запросы это не критично, однако если данные запрашиваются одни и те же, то организуйте стор(store) для хранения данных и не вызывайте их повторно на каждой странице.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov благодарю вас. Ну я так понимаю что если к примеру у меня есть компонент dropzone, и он мне нужен на двух страницах, я его если подгружаю на одном маршруте асинхронно, на другом маршруте где он нужен, он уже повторно не загружается, если даже я его загружаю по новой, потому что он уже в теге head есть

Comment: Нет, вы не правильно поняли, все компоненты уже на стороне клиента в js файле, после его первого запроса и вы вольны показывать его на любой странице. А сами данные стоит хранить в сторе, те которые вы подгружаете. за исключением случаев, если они регулярно обновляются. На беке. Поэтому сами компоненты уже в теле это только вес страницы.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov похоже я немного запутался, я ведь использую vue-route, по факту страница не перезагружается при переходах по страницам